# Extra Character Whenever I Print Out at An Output

Tags: c

I am trying to do a FLAMES program as an assignment and since I can't exactly post my whole code here, I will type in the part of the code that seems to be causing me errors since whenever I print out something, there are unexpected extra characters going with the output.

I used a similar code as this one:

```
int main(){
    char chari[100], temp[100];
    int i, c;

    printf("Enter a name: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", chari);

    for (i=1; chari[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }

    c = i;

    for (i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        printf("%i < %i\n", i, c);
        temp[i] = chari[i];
    }

    printf("%s \n", temp);

    return 0;

}
```

I've been tweaking the codes for hours now but I still can't seem to find the problem. I'm also counting the number of letters in the string so I can stop some part of my program later on.

**Input: cool**

**Expected output: cool**

**Actual Output: cool(<-t**

Comment: Note that the `"%["` format is terminated by the `"]"`. There's no `"s"` in the format specification.

Comment: And if you [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), do you notice if you copy the string null-terminator as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to copy the terminating null character.

After your first loop `c = i;` holds the index of the 0 byte.
In the second loop you run until `i < c`, i.e. you do not copy that 0 byte
Without terminating nul your string is as long as another random 0 byte is found in memory.

Within a function only static variables are initialized. Hence your `temp` array hold indetermined values and you cannot rely to get a 0 character where you need it.

You need to copy 1 more byte.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much for this explanation. It's kind of hard to get this without any help. My program runs smoothly now, I just added 1 to the c=1.

Comment: That's why running the program in a debugger is important. It should reveal these things. BTW: You might consider accepting the answer.